# Get current woocommerce product id in functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get current product id but its returns null;

I want to use product id in below function

```
new WC_Product( $product_id);
```

note that i want get product id in "functions.php" file.

I tried

```
global $post;
$id = $post->ID
```

and

```
global $product;
$id = $product->id;
```

But that's not working

Comment: Where exactly you want Product_ID because in WordPress there are a lot of scopes?

Comment: i want that in function.php file and globally   @Adam abdul shakoor

Comment: almost right, do like this $id = $product->get_id();

Comment: I understand that you will use that in functions but where exactly you are going to call this function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood the answer
in woocommerce you can't access globally product object
you have a way for handle this Issue

you should use below code in function.php

```
wc_get_product()->get_id();
```

Comment: This is a better idea than using global variables. Always avoid global variables if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Since Woocommerce 3.0 you have to use:

```
global $product;
$id = $product->get_id();
```